# setting up Ms exchange 2003 on sbs2003 to leave a copy of email on the mail server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

We have sbs-2003 using exchange in a small office, with outlook 07 on the desktops. 
I am shortly going to get rid of the server, and have the desktops access the mail directly.
I have a spare computer out of the server loop which i want to test outlook on, however after setting up the pop account, outlook always says there is no mail to download! i can send ok.
I suspect exchange is not leaving a copy of email on the mail server, but cant find where or how to confirm this. Ive googled my but off - but cant find any help anywhere, hope someone out there can help me.
Thanks - col

Answer (score 0):

The setting to leave a copy of the Email on the server is within Outlook (client side).

Within the account settings, on the POP3 mailbox you can click advanced and there is a setting in there to leave a copy.

However this will only act upon new emails received the ones already downloaded need to be exported to PST then reimported once the setting is turned on so they are placed back on the Server.

At least that is one of several methods. Happy to help further if needed.

Comment: Sorry just re read your question your relaying pop3 via exchange? This cannot be done natively so you must have a third party like exchangepop3 or igetmail… if we knew which one was being used could probably help more.

Comment: Hi CharlesH, thanks for your help. Yes - at the moment the mail is outlook through exchange on the server. Outlook hasnt got the options to leave mail one the mail server in this setup, however i was hoping to have our spare computer which isnt in the server network setup outlook direct to the mail server to test everything -- but cant find how or if i can get exchange to leave messages on the mail server. Can it be done?

Comment: @colunder NP in a standard setup you have your domain name call it ex.com which would have MX records that point to your office's IP and route all Email directly to Exchange, your clients would then connect in whatever fashion be it POP3, MAPI, etc to Exchange. However your setup appears to be you have a web based email server (like gmail), exchange and clients. You've bypassed exchange on a test machine and no emails are available on the web based email sever, correct?

Comment: @colunder If so you need to find out what is polling those Emails to Exchange because Exchange doesn't do this natively so it has to be a third party tool.

Comment: thanks again. As you can gather, im no expert in exchange, or sbs, however im sure the server is setup as you mentioned in the standard way. We have MX records, and the office pc's get their mail from exchange. I will do some more investigating when i get to work tomorrow to see if we have a third party polling the email. cheers

Answer (score 0):

for future users who need an answer to this question, the problem is in the "Microsoft connector for pop3 mailboxes" part of exchange, and as Charles points out, cant be configured manually, you need to use Popcon or other third party software. There are a couple of hacks that can make the connector leave a copy on the mailhost, but aparently you end up downloading the same emails over and over when you do this, and i havent found an updated hack or answer to solve this. Soo- thanks again for your input charles, i give up and will do the third party thing. Colunder